# Mongodb map reduce result format changes

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

i'm using the java api and call the following map reduce command:

```
MAP
function() { 
emit('nogroup',{endtime: this.endtime, _owner: this._owner}); 
}

REDUCE
function Reduce(key, values) { 
var res = 3426533531976; 
for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
if ( values[i].endtime < res && values[i]._owner == null  ) 
res = values[i].endtime; 
} 
return res;
}
```

with this code

```
String map = "function() { emit('nogroup',{endtime: this.endtime, _owner: this._owner}); }";
String reduce = "function Reduce(key, values) { var res = 9426533531976; for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) { if ( values[i].endtime < res && values[i]._owner == null  ) res = values[i].endtime; } return res;}";
MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(userdataCollection, map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);
MapReduceOutput out = userdataCollection.mapReduce(cmd);
```

sometimes the result looks loke this

```
{ "_id" : "nogroup" , "value" : { "floatApprox" : 1.426628475177E12}}
```

and sometimes like this

```
{ "_id" : "nogroup" , "value" : 9.426533531976E12}
```

how can i extract my long result always with the same code?

at the moment i have

```
for (DBObject a : out.results()) {
    return ((BasicDBObject) a.get("value")).getLong("floatApprox");
}
```

but this works only for the floatApprox variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a check after:

```
res = values[i].endtime;
```

eg.

```
res = values[i].endtime;
if ( typeof res == "object"){
  res = res.floatApprox;
}
```